# Using an undefined control sequence as value for ProcessKeyOptions

Tags: expl3, package-options

I have a test L3 package (that does not do anything useful for now) where a key is used to set a lua variable :

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {package}  {}  {}  {}
  
 \keys_define:nn {MWE} {
   MWEkey .code:n = \lua_now:e { luaVar = "\lua_escape:n {#1}" }
 }
 
 \ProcessKeyOptions[MWE]
```

However, if I set a document

```tex
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage[MWEkey={\essai}]{package}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

I get an Undefined command error pertaining to `\essai`, before reaching the package code.

If I say

```tex
\def\essai{t}
\usepackage[MWEkey={\essai}]{package}
```

then `luaVar` is set to `\essai`. This is fine, because we are not actually going to interpret `\essai` as a TeX command in the lua code.

I read that `\ProcessKeyOptions` was better than `\ProcessKeysOptions` because it does not have expansion problems, but here I am confused as to why `\essai` not being defined causes a problem.

Is there a tweak in it to manage this situation ?

Comment: it would (as always) help if you provided an example, but probably it is failing in an `\edef` setting up the (unused) classical option handler.  it is better/safer to se `\usepackage{siunitx}\sisetup{.....}` than `\usepackage[...]{siunitx}`

Comment: I will clarify that this is a test package.

Comment: `\usepackage` expands the option list before the package is loaded so there is nothing you can do in the package to stop that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safer to separate the key handling

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{package}
\MWEsetup{MWEkey={\essai}}

\directlua{texio.write('luaVar=' .. luaVar)}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

---

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesExplPackage
  {package}  {}  {}  {}
  
 \keys_define:nn {MWE} {
   MWEkey .code:n = \lua_now:e { luaVar = "\lua_escape:n {#1}" }
 }
 
 \ProcessKeyOptions[MWE]

\newcommand\MWEsetup[1]{\SetKeys[MWE]{#1}}
```

produces

```
 luaVar=\essai
```

On the terminal.

"Safe" keys can be set via the pakage options, but not this.